# Text shows under the overlay for Jquery Tools Overlay in IE 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, drupal-6

Link : http://designbracket.com/ . Click on Our Services and the links under it. I have used Overlay of Jquery Tools to display overlay when any link is clicked. This is a drupal site . The problem is that though the overlay is opening as expected however the text is appearing under it in IE 7 while that does not happen in FF or Chrome (obviously not :)).

I think this has something to do with the z-index bug of IE 7. However, in spite of wasting two days on this stupid issue I haven't had any headway.

Kindly help. Any help or suggestions would be deeply appreciated. In case the question is ambiguous please let me know and I would try and include more details.

Thanks

Comment: I seem to have the same problem in FF 3.5.6 (Mac OS X). The text appears underneath the overlay box, slightly to the right? Maybe the problem is not just present in IE7, and I'd therefore advise taking a look at your CSS.

Comment: Hi Ben.. Thanks fr the suggestion but somehow I am not facing any problem in FF (I have 3.0.16) or Chrome. The code I am using is  exactly same as on http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/multiple.html . While the code stand alone works fine (even in IE 7 and 6) but implementing it within drupal is seemingly becoming a pain. Still thanks for the suggestion would give it a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old ticket, but i'm just going to put this out there because it helped me.

I experienced overlay issues with IE7 and jquery tools as a result of having my overlay divs inside a [grid 960](http://960.gs) div. Changing the z-index (`z-index: 9999999 !important;`) didn't help at all.

To resolve i simply moved my overlay divs to just before my closing `</body>` tag which was outside any .container or .grid classes.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know: Thank you for answering this old ticket, for it helped me enormously!

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem where the overlay was displayed behind an Expose-mask in IE7, thus leaving no elements on the page clickable, including the overlay. Adding this in the `overlay()` settings solved the issue:

```
onLoad:  function() {
  this.getOverlay().insertAfter('#exposeMask');
}
```

Comment: This is better solution because don't force me to change my HTML.

Comment: This solution works better for me because I am unable to place the overlay divs right before the closing `body` tag. There's one caveat though: the `onLoad` event doesn't occur until the overlay is completely visible (i.e.- fade-in transitions are finished), so your content won't appear in front of the overlay mask until the mask is finished transitioning.

Comment: Also, I tried using the `onBeforeLoad` event, but it didn't work properly. The overlay wouldn't come to the front until the second time I opened it. I think I might go file a bug report now...